# Popover shadow gone with iOS 13

Tags: ios, ios13

On devices running iOS 13, the popover shadow is no longer shows. This happens when the popover is shown on a ViewController that contains a custom UIView with a CAEAGLLayer backing layer directly under it.

I know CAEAGLLayer is deprecated in iOS 13 but there must be a way to resolve this.

Funny enough when taking a screenshot to show here the issue the shadow shows up on the screenshot! So weird...

[image]

I tried creating a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView and the shadow set in it worked fine.

```
UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverController = viewController.popoverPresentationController;
popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
popoverController.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [PopoverBackgroundView class];
```

[image]

Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated! I spent all day trying to figure this one out. :/

Comment: It seems that the project needs to be changed from OpenGL to Apple's 3D Graphics API: Metal.

Comment: Yep, eventually, but at the moment not looking for doing such a big change. Darn Apple...

Comment: +1: exactly the same issue here, including that the shadow magically does show up in screenshots! I've experimented a bit and found inconsistent results, but sometimes changing the layer's `opaque` property can bring the shadow back, and sometimes adding an invisible view to the window can do the same. Neither are consistent enough to solve the problem in all cases, unfortunately. I'll give your workaround a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for those running into something similar I was able to patch a temp fix by using the following method inside the view controller's viewWillDisplay method.

```
+ (void)fixShadowForViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    if (viewController.popoverPresentationController)
    {
        NSOperatingSystemVersion ios13 = (NSOperatingSystemVersion){13, 0, 0};
        if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:ios13])
        {
           UIView *popoverView = viewController.popoverPresentationController.containerView;
           popoverView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
           popoverView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.16f;
           popoverView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
           popoverView.layer.shadowRadius = 32.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            // The arrow doesn't get colored properly on iOS 12 and lower so we take the background
            // color of the view controller and apply it to make it match.
            viewController.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = viewController.view.backgroundColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: this is brilliant! I ended up swizzling the `viewWillAppear:` method of `UIViewController` so that I don't have to add this code to all my popovers, and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for posting this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the shadow of a `UIPopoverPresentationController` in the `prepareForPopoverPresentation(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController)` method of a `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`:

```
func prepareForPopoverPresentation(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
        guard let popoveContainerView = popoverPresentationController.containerView else { return }
        popoveContainerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        popoveContainerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        popoveContainerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4)
        popoveContainerView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    }
```